# How to get city , state and Country name by Pincode in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, state, city

I have Five textFields and I want to autofill Area,City ,State and Country when I enter the pin code number.

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreLocation

class CreateGroupView: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
   //View Did Load
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    let location: String = "305621"//"yourPINCode"
    let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location,completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if ((placemarks?.count)! > 0) {
            let placemark: CLPlacemark = (placemarks?[0])!
            let country : String = placemark.country!
            let state: String = placemark.administrativeArea!
            print(country)
            print(state)
        }
    } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
  }
}
```

How can I do that ?
Thanks

Comment: I didn't get it in OBJ-C so i asked.
@Anbu

Comment: take this one for convert objectiveC to swift https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

Comment: if you not get the answer , reply here I open the question you get answer

Comment: No I didn't get answer.
error :- Use of undeclared type 'MKPlacemark'

Comment: can you update the question once

Comment: I updated check it please.
I am not able to get in swift.
Thanks

Comment: which one you not get I am not able to get i

Comment: That link you given na.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use CLGeocoder to get detail of address from PIN code, here is sample code.

```
   let location: String = "yourpincode"
let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    if ((placemarks?.count)! > 0) {
        let placemark: CLPlacemark = (placemarks?[0])!
        let country : String = placemark.country!
        let state: String = placemark.administrativeArea!
        print(state);
    }
} as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

Comment: Actually I am totally new in that.
So which frameworks and what and all thing are required for this?

Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011, you need to Import CoreLocation framework. Nothing else, it will work.

Comment: Ok let me try .
Thanks

Comment: Hey I am getting error :- Use of undeclared type 'MKPlacemark'

Comment: exception is coming.

Comment: Anything missed like delegate or?

Comment: no, completion handler is already there..what pincode you are using for testing ? What is exception detail?

Comment: Actually if i am not using completion handler then Xcode showing error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129514/discussion-between-ios-devloper-and-kishor0011).

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
for city.

Comment: let inlandWaterr : String = placemark.inlandWater!
                let SubLocalit : String = (placemark.subLocality)!
                print(SubLocalit)
                    
                print(inlandWaterr)